# How sort works for database with limited memory

Tags: database, algorithm, sorting, data-structures

How the data stored in the database, what DS is used. Say i have a ssn table having the field as Name, Age, Sex, address, work status, etc, i want to sort the table by age. How the sorting will be performed as the system memory will be limited compared to the volume of the data.

As far as i can understand that this sorting can't be performed in memory, even if we take the age as only field as the memory is limited, in that case the sorting has to happen in external storage, using the merge sort, please let me know if any other better approaches are available.

Comment: Read about external k-way merge sort!

Comment: my bet is that most DBMSes query plan will choose if you can sort it in memory or, if there isn't enough, use some sort of external merge-sort approach

Comment: google for a paper called "Implementing Sorting in Database Systems" by GOETZ GRAEFE